# В чём ошибка. Не могу нормально создать функцию для ввода массива

Tags: c++

сам я студетнт, нам дали задание(основная проблема выделена **жирным** шрифтом):
Выполнить следующее задание для заданного текста. Оформить задание в
виде набора функций: **функция создания массива слов**, функция получения резуль-
тирующей строки. Характеристикой слова назовем длину содержащейся в нем максимальной серии(подряд идущих одинаковых символов). Упорядочить слова заданного предложения в соответствии с ростом их характеристик. Записать их в результирующую строку.

данный код представлен не полностью, но основную проблему показывает полностью.

помогите пожалуйста!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const int n = 2500;

void  enter_wordle(char wordle[])
    {
        cout << "Enter some english!! word: ";
        cin >> wordle;
        cout << endl << wordle << endl;
    }

int main()
{
    char* wordle = new char[number];

    enter_wordle(wordle);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну для начала, что вы передаете в char[number]? Number как бы я хотел так и не нашел, подставив туда по логике n - как размер массива(константу) ваш код работает. Функция выполняет то, что вы ей и описали.

Answer (score 0):

```
void  enter_wordle()
{
    int number;
    string word;
    cout << "Enter size of array: ";
    cin >> number;
    string * wordle = new string[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; ++i) {
    cout << "Enter some english!! word: ";
    cin >> word;
    *wordle += word;

}
    
        cout << *wordle;

}
```

Сделал массив слов,а не символов,как у тебя.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]